# Redeploy Docker image to aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have uploaded my docker image to the AWS EC2 instance. Now I have update my code and modify it, I have created a new docker image with a new tag and upload it to the same docker image repository and want to upload a new docker image to the same ec2 instance.
i connect AWS with ssh client and write this line

```
docker run --restart=always -p 8000:8000 myDockerImageRepositary:myTag
```

it gives me an error

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dreamy_engelbart (0be73435f9a848ead131e0e15160ce9cb7333fa84565291d027e6a9d6467c476): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated.
```

I think the error is because my previous docker image is running on port 8000 but I have to update that docker image with the new one and don't know how to do that.

Thank you

Comment: Is the old docker still running? You have to stop that one as port 8000 is in use by that.

Comment: can you tell me how to stop, I have tried to stop the instance but I can open instance to update my docker

Comment: You can do `docker ps`, get the id , do `docker stop $id` and then `docker rm $id`. Once it's stopped, launch the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `sudo netstat -nltpu` to confirm what application is running on that port. If it is docker then it means you probably didn't kill the previous docker container that was running on that port. If you don't have any other containers running, you can just stop all containers using this `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`

If you have other containers running, you can run `docker ps` to get details of the container running on that port, then run `docker stop CONTAINER_ID` to stop the container.